# Youtube like (rating) not working

Tags: java, youtube, codenameone

I have signed in and get auth token, but when i click in the like button, the youtube rating is not working. What else i have to do to make it work? if i use the url in the web browser it ask for authorize and execute then it works. But from the app, it is not happening yet. Also I have set all required client id, client secret etc as well.

```
connectionForYoutubeData();

f.setLayout(new BoxLayout(BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
Button signIn = new Button("signIn");
Button like = new Button("Like");
like.setText("Like: " + likeCount);

Container mainContainer = new Container(new BoxLayout(BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
mainContainer.add(signIn);
mainContainer.add(like);
f.add(mainContainer);

signIn.addActionListener((e) -> {
    String clientId = "704790222159-n1cpb3g1q3plirslu5739apc0gnnv4pp.apps.googleusercontent.com";
    String redirectURI = "https://www.youtube.com/";
    String clientSecret = "q_cxGCCbX5GVC99kxgstjksB";
    Login gc = GoogleConnect.getInstance();
    gc.setClientId(clientId);
    gc.setRedirectURI(redirectURI);
    gc.setClientSecret(clientSecret);
    gc.setCallback(new LoginCallback() {
        @Override
        public void loginFailed(String errorMessage) {
            like.addActionListener((c) -> {
                Label newLabel = new Label("beck unsuccess");
                f.add(newLabel);
            });
        }
        @Override
        public void loginSuccessful() {
            Dialog.show("Logged In", "you are currently logged in ", "OK", null);
        }
    });
    if (!gc.isUserLoggedIn()) {
        gc.doLogin();
    } else {
        token = gc.getAccessToken().getToken();
    }
});

like.addActionListener((e) -> {
    ConnectionRequest cr = new ConnectionRequest() {
        @Override
        protected void readResponse(InputStream input) throws IOException {
            super.readResponse(input);
        }
        @Override
        protected void postResponse() {
            super.postResponse();
        }
    };
    cr.setPost(true);
    cr.setUrl("https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/youtube/v3/youtube.videos.rate?" + "id=" + "Z98hXV9GmzY" + "&rating=like" + "&access_token=" + token + "&key=AIzaSyCAETrMkZeJ_nTq4ZdP1Jq6BFtA_11TR6I"); 
    cr.setDuplicateSupported(true);
    NetworkManager.getInstance().addToQueueAndWait(cr);
});
f.revalidate();
```

Sign-in response header:

```
Transfer-Encoding=[chunked]
null=[HTTP/1.1 200 OK]
Alt-Svc=[quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="32,31,30,29,28,27,26,25"]
Server=[GSE]
X-Content-Type-Options=[nosniff]
Pragma=[no-cache]
Date=[Fri, 01 Apr 2016 04:17:24 GMT]
Alternate-Protocol=[443:quic]
Accept-Ranges=[none]
X-Frame-Options=[SAMEORIGIN]
Cache-Control=[no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate]
Vary=[Origin,Accept-Encoding, X-Origin]
Expires=[Fri, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT]
X-XSS-Protection=[1; mode=block]
Content-Type=[application/json; charset=UTF-8]
```

like response header:

```
X-Frame-Options=[DENY]
null=[HTTP/1.1 200 OK]
Server=[Google Frontend]
Content-Length=[994]
Date=[Fri, 01 Apr 2016 04:18:11 GMT]
Content-Type=[text/html; charset=utf-8]
```

Update:

```
@Override
protected void readResponse(InputStream input) throws IOException {
 JSONParser jSONParser = new JSONParser();
 results = jSONParser.parseJSON(new InputStreamReader(input));
 System.out.println("parsed results: " + results);
    }
```

if i try to read the response as above it gives following error in the output

```
Expected true for key value!
Expected true for key value!
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
Expected true for key value!
Expected true for key value!
Expected true for key value!
Expected null for key value!
Expected null for key value!
Expected null for key value!
Expected true for key value!
Expected true for key value!
Expected true for key value!
Expected true for key value!
parsed results: {}
```

Update 2:
I came to know that I'm using the wrong API for rating. The right one is

```
cr.setUrl("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos/rate?id=" + "kF94Jwx9ugU" + "&rating=like&access_token=" + token + "&key=xxxxxx");
```

but it gives 403 Forbidden error. P.S i have already sign in and got the token value as well. So it should not be auth error i guess. Also response length is null and so is response body. Hence fraud detection part by google is not valid here.

Comment: Do you get any Exception ?

Comment: no... nothing.... i get signed in, access token as well but the no. of likes remain same

Comment: hello @Berger it is giving 403 Forbidden exception now.

Answer (score 0):

I notice you don't check the response to the like call which might include JSON or data that will indicate why this isn't accepted. I suggest using the network monitor to view that response.

Notice that invoking such API's might be challenging as Google might have fraud detection in place and might have already marked you as a person who is tying to circumvent the like system.

Comment: i updated response from network monitor above, please have a look.

Comment: Is there nothing in the response body? It says there are 994 bytes so it's giving some answer

Comment: if i try to read the response it gives error output as above updated.

Comment: Read it to a string and print the string. The response should be listed in the network monitor

Comment: sorry Shai, my mistake I came to know that I'm using the wrong API for rating. I updated the right one above but it gives 403 Forbidden error. P.S i have already sign in and got the token value as well. So it should not be auth error i guess.

Comment: Notice that you are trying to parse the response instead of actually reading it to a String. In the response tab (3rd tab in the network monitor) you should see the data of the response. I'm guessing you are getting forbidden errors because you don't have the permissions to access this API but I'm not really familiar with this API.

Comment: I reference this url: codenameone.com/google-login.html but it lacks one line ie. gc.setScope(); After i added the line it worked, without it, it isnot working. However it only works in simulator & doesnt run in the device